# jQuery UI Accordion will not reopen after close

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery

I have a form in jQuery UI Accordion.

With this code, a visitor must validate the first panel and only then the next accordion panel opens. However, if the visitor wants to go back to first panel it doesn't let it go.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#accordion").accordion({ event: false });

    $('#openfirst').click(function () {

        if (varification is okay then) {

            $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 1 });

                // cancel submit
                return false;

            } else {

                alert('Please acknowledge the following before proceeding.');

            }

        });

        $('#opensecond').click(function () {


            if (varification is okay then) {

                $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 2 });

            } else {

                alert('Please acknowledge the following before proceeding.');

            }

        });

        $('#openthird').click(function () {

            if (varification is okay then) {

                $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 3 });

                // cancel submit
                return false;

            } else {

                alert('Please acknowledge the following before proceeding.');

            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can some one help please..!!!????

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ event: false });
```

try using

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "disable" );
```

and upon user verification, use

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "enable" ); //for manual operation of tabs
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: # }); //for code generated operation of tabs
```